# How to get the minimum unit from DateTime

Tags: python, datetime

if the DateTime has been converted to string, the method is

```
x = '1908-07-03 8:20'  
# x = '1908-07-03'  
if ':' in x:
    print 'hour' 
else:
    print 'day'
```

But how can I process the DateTime format directly?

```
x = datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 7, 0, 30, 3, 628556)
# x = datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 7)
```

Comment: what does this mean? are you trying to find an easier way to see if a string is accurate to the hour or day?

Answer (score -1):

Also, you can:

```
def is_hour_in(datetime_string):
  result =  True if len(datetime_string.split()) == 2 else False
  return result
```

It will return `True` if day in passed string datetime.

If you want to display minimum unit, rewrite it to next:

```
def show_minimum_(datetime_string):
  result =  datetime_string.split()[-1]
  return result
```